# Isn't "Todo lo que tengo solo tiene precio si lo comparto junto a ti" subjunctive?

Tags: subjuntivo, letras-de-canciones

Isn't the sentence from Jennifer Lopez's song *Pa'ti*,

> "Todo lo que tengo solo tiene precio si lo comparto junto a ti"

supposed to trigger the subjunctive? It isn't certain whether or not she shares the things she has, which leads me to believe that it should be "comparte" instead of "comparto". Am I just wrong here?

Comment: Not at all. There is no subjunctive trigger here.

Comment: *Comparte* means "s/he shares"; *comparto* means "I share". Both are from the present indicative of the verb *compartir*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subjunctive mood expresses a possibility, something that may happen or not. But this is a bit different. Consider the same sentence, but written in the subjunctive:

> Todo lo que tengo solo *tendría* precio si lo *compartiera* junto a ti.

(Notice that we also need to change the antecedent verb to use the conditional).

In this case, you are right, we mean that what I have would only have a price in case I shared it with you.

But the original means that it has a price only because I am actually sharing it with you. Another slightly different construction with the same meaning:

> Todo lo que tengo solo tiene precio *cuando* lo comparto junto a ti.

Both this sentence and the original in the song mean that I am sharing what I have, and this is the reason why it has a value. There is no uncertainty here, and this is the reason why we do not use the subjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? "*Todo lo que tengo solo tiene precio si lo comparto junto a ti*"

No, no es subjuntivo, es simplemente presente de indicativo, si fuera subjuntivo sería "(yo) comparta" ó "(nosotros) compartamos".

Lo que ocurre aquí es que existe un mal uso del Español, utilizando "precio" con el sentido de "valor". La frase correcta sería "Todo lo que tengo, solo tiene valor si lo comparto junto a ti".

Hay que entender que Jennifer López, aunque habla Español, aprendido primordialmente de su abuela, como a veces ha indicado, comete bastantes fallos cuando se expresa en Español ya que a pesar de sus orígenes, el Inglés es la lengua habitual que utiliza y por tanto en algunos casos posee bastantes deficiencias y en el Español Norteamericano estos desencuentros es normal encontrarlos.

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos!

Diego M.